# Conceptual Doubt in Limit and Function

Tags: limits, functions

My teacher solved this question in class today. He said that as the function was non-uniformly defined I had to find LHL and RHL separately and verify whether they are equal to confirm the limit exists.

$\lim _{x\to 5}\left(\frac{x^2-9x+20}{x-\left[x\right]}\right)$, where [.] is GIF.

I can't really see how this function is non-uniformly defined, could anyone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!

Comment: On this site, we prefer questions to have context: a quick description of the terms you use (whether standard or not), and a summary of your problem-solving strategy.  For example, I've never heard the term "non-uniformly defined" before; although I can guess what it means, it's better if you tell me.  The latter can be an explicit description of your work, or just some similar problems that you do know how to solve (and why you can't use the same solution techniques here).  We use context to know what level to pitch answers at (although it seems you got an answer here anyways).

Comment: Oh, sorry. Will follow this the next time 

Comment: No problem.  And, again, welcome!  We're glad to have you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its is non-uniformly defined as its involves [x]

As $[5-h]=4$  and $[5+h]= 5$ , so the denominator have value $1$ in LHL and value $0$ in RHL.

**EDIT** :-

And ans for this question will be

$\lim _{x\to 5}\left(\frac{x^2-9x+20}{x-\left[x\right]}\right)$,

=$\lim _{x\to 5}\left(\frac{(x-4)(x-5)}{x-\left[x\right]}\right)$,

and $x\to 5$ thus $(x-4)\to 1$

giving

=$\lim _{x\to 5}\left(\frac{(x-5)}{x-\left[x\right]}\right)$,

LHL=$\left(\frac{[(5-h)-5]}{5-h-\left[5-h\right]}\right)$ =$\left(\frac{-h}{1}\right)$=$0$

RHL=$\left(\frac{[(5+h)-5]}{5+h-\left[5+h\right]}\right)$ =$\left(\frac{h}{h}\right)$=1

LHL $\neq$ RHL

Comment: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: please edit the last line for me